# Make an image invisible to Search Engines and Facebook?

Tags: css, image, facebook, xhtml, search-engine

When I try to add a link of Facebook, it reads every image as a thumbnail and I do not want that. Is there anyway I can remove that feature of the image, because if it reads it via Facebook, then Search Engines will be able to index the image. Any idea without having to make a specific class in the css that uses the background image as the image itself?

Thank you,
Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use .htaccess to do that.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.jpg$ http://some-image-location [NC,L]
#RewriteRule \.jpg$ - [NC,L]  # this will result in failed request
```

if you put this in the root folder, then all *.jpg on your site will appear only to your domain pages, anyone linking from outside your domain will not get the image.

If you want to restrict images from only one folder then put the htaccess in that folder.

**Note that these rules are very crude and will prevent everyone(Google, Yahoo, even hotlinking) other than your own domain from accessing the images.**

Comment: @Aaron Brewer You are welcome. I forgot to mention, if you want to just restrict one image, say TopSecret.jpg, then change the RewriteRule to have `TopSecret\.jpg$` To include more types use `\.(jpg|gif|png)$`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can select a certain image to hide.
You can hide all JPG files from search bots with this though:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add server-side code to only emit the `<img>` tag if the `User-Agent` isn't Facebook or a spider.